# Cannot understand how to do this loop structure

Tags: php, loops

Can someone help me on the way with a `SELECT` (or more if needed) and some php `loops`. I've been trying to come up with a solution for 2 days now.

There's this 12 column grid I use which is `movable` and `resizable`. I store the data of it, such as **x-axis**, **y-axix**, **width**, **height**.

Here is an example of the database table `elements`:

```
| id | page_id | element_type | element_x | element_y | width | height | element_content
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 45 | 1       | title        | 0         | 0         | 12    | 1      | Content
| 70 | 1       | button       | 6         | 2         | 6     | 1      | Content
| 23 | 1       | form         | 4         | 1         | 4     | 1      | Content
| 55 | 1       | rich-textfield 0         | 1         | 4     | 1      | Content
| 101| 1       | gallery      | 8         | 1         | 4     | 1      | Content
```

As you can see the height doesn't matter because it's always `1`.

This example structure would show this in my resizable grid:

[image: a busy cat]

So far I got this to `SELECT` the grid items:

```
$id = 1;
$selectElements = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `elements` WHERE `page_id` = :id");
$selectElements->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$selectElements->execute();
```

What I have in mind is something like

```
foreach element_y

    <div class="row">

        // loop to loop thru all element_x's per element_y 

    </div>

endforeach
```

Note that every element_y number needs to be outputted just one time each. so instead of:

0 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 it should be **0 - 1 - 2**

Is it possible to make what I have in mind or am I thinking the complete wrong way? :) Highly appreciated!

P.S. If the question is not clear enough tell me, I will change my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest something along the lines of the following:

Make sure your SQL orders by `element_y` and `element_x`:

```
SELECT * FROM `elements` 
    WHERE `page_id` = :id 
    ORDER BY `element_y` ASC, `element_x` ASC
```

That way, you'll be sure to have the correct order already.

Then, transform your array into a slightly different structure with something like this:

```
$elements_grouped = [];

foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    $elements_grouped[$element['element_y']][$key] = $element;
}
```

That will put your elements in an array with `element_y` keys holding their respective elements.

Then, you can loop over that, and in in a second loop loop over the elements (using your pseudocode):

```
foreach elements_grouped as row

    <div class="row">

        foreach row as element
            // output element
        endforeach

    </div>

endforeach
```

Comment: s is a really great solution! I got it to work except for one thing: the first element isn't inside the loop. I got 5 elements that need to be looped but only get 4

Comment: @joostdelange this is gonna be hard to debug without actual code and data. I'd suggest you var_dump your elements before and after the transformation, and then try to figure out where the error is.

Comment: In the end I found out what the problem was: `$row = $selectElements->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` caused skipping the first row for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You should use multi dimensional array ( key and value) to handle all data first

```
$handleData = array();
foreach($result as $item){
    $handleData[$item['element_y'] => array(
        $item['element_x'] => array(
            'element_type' => $item['element_type'],
            'width' => $item['width '],
            'element_content' => $item['element_content']
        )
    )
}
```

After that, you just need to printout $handleData